# Python error when I want to print

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

This code works perfectly:

```
class MyStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
def on_success(self, data): 
    txt=json.dumps(data)
    #print txt
    cur2 = cnx.cursor()
    sql="INSERT INTO TWTemp(TWTempTXT,TWTempEstadoCdg) VALUES('"+txt+"',0)"
    cur2.execute(sql)
    cnx.commit()
    self.disconnect()

def on_error(self, status_code, data):
    print status_code, data
    self.disconnect()
```

but when line 4 ("print txt") is uncommented, I see the following error:

```
File "tw.py", line 13
print txt
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Somebody help me?
Regards
Bruno

Comment: Are you sure you have only tabs or only spaces?

Comment: Thanks Guillaume the problem is the TABS, I replaced tabs with spaces and it works!

Comment: @GuillaumeThomas you should add this as answer so that it can be accepted and removed from unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace tabs by spaces or the opposite. It's usually a mix of tabs & spaces when python tells you this.